# What is wrong with this approach in comparing two rows in mastermind?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Created a function with two ints and two lists.
This approach still double counts.
Example: row 1: 1,2,2,3
row 2: 1,4,2,5

It shows *wrongPosition: 1 and samePlace: 2* instead of **samePlace: 2 and wrongPosition:0**.
Also, do you have any suggestion as to how to optimise this code?

```cs
private void CompareRows()
{
    if (_resaultPawns.Length != _actualRowPawns.Length)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Arrays have different length");
        return;
     }
     int swrongPosition = 0;
     int samePlace = 0;
     List<int> alreadyCounted = new List<int>();
     List<int> alreadyCountedColors = new List<int>();

     // Check for same position with same color
     for (int i = 0; i < _resaultPawns.Length; i++)
     {
         if (_resaultPawns[i].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color == _actualRowPawns[i].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color)
         {
             if (!alreadyCounted.Contains(i))
             {
                  samePlace++;
                  alreadyCounted.Add(i);
             }
         }
     }
    
     // Check for wrong position with same color
     for (int i = 0; i < _resaultPawns.Length; i++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < _actualRowPawns.Length; j++)
         {
             if (_resaultPawns[i].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color == _actualRowPawns[j].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color && !alreadyCounted.Contains(i) && !alreadyCountedColors.Contains(j))
             {
                 if (!alreadyCounted.Contains(i) && !alreadyCountedColors.Contains(j))
                 {
                     swrongPosition++;
                     alreadyCountedColors.Add(j);
                     alreadyCounted.Add(i);
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Codereview would a good place to ask

Comment: No @BugFinder , broken code is [not ready for review](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) until it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

See https://dotnetfiddle.net/91GVVe

I looked at this from optimizations/maintainability first and refactoring the code a bit seems to already have solved the issue as well ^^

```
    var samePlace = new List<int>(4);
    var wrongPosition = new List<int>(4);

    for (var i = 0; i < _resaultPawns.Length; i++)
    {
        if (_resaultPawns[i].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color == _actualRowPawns[i].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color)
        {
            // Check for 'alreadyCounted.Contains' is redundan at this stage
            
            // No additional counter needed - simply add items and use the list Count later on
            samePlace.Add(i);
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < _resaultPawns.Length; i++)
    {
        // Can directly skip as already counted
        if (samePlace.Contains(i)) continue;
        
        for (var j = 0; j < _actualRowPawns.Length; j++)
        {
            // can directly skip as would have been upper loop match
            // slightly chaper though than using the 'samePlace.Contains(j)' below
            if (i == j) continue;
            
            // skip as well to not re-use already exact matches 
            if (samePlace.Contains(j)) continue;
            
            // skip to not use twice
            if (wrongPosition.Contains(j)) continue;
            
            if (_resaultPawns[i].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color == _actualRowPawns[j].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color)
            {
                wrongPosition.Add(j);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    var wrongPositionCount = wrongPosition.Count;
    var samePlaceCount = samePlace.Count;
```

I guess the main bit I added was

```
if (samePlace.Contains(j)) continue;
```

=> you also want to ignore if a `j` index was already seen before by the first loop as it is already an exact match.

In your example

```
1,2,2,3 

1,4,2,5
```

even though the index `3` (=value `2`) was already counted as an exact match it was used again as an alternative position for index `1`, a case you didn't check for as it is neither in your `alreadyCounted` nor in `alreadyCountedColour`

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty simple to just do this:

```
var hidden = new[] { 1, 2, 2, 3 };
var first = new[] { 1, 4, 2, 5 };

int sp = 0;
int wp = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    if (first[i] == hidden[i])
        sp++;
    else
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            if (first[i] == hidden[j] && first[j] != hidden[j])
            {
                wp++;
                break;
            }
}

Console.WriteLine($"Same Place: {sp}, Wrong Place: {wp}");
```

That outputs `Same Place: 2, Wrong Place: 0`.

---

It looks like a more complicated approach is needed to cover all cases:

```
var hidden = new[] { 1, 2, 2, 3 };
var first  = new[] { 1, 4, 2, 5 };

var paired =
    first
        .Zip(hidden, (f, h) => (first: f, hidden: h))
        .ToLookup(x => x.first == x.hidden);

int sp = paired[true].Count();

var unmatched_hidden = paired[false].ToLookup(x => x.first);
var unmatched_first = paired[false].ToLookup(x => x.hidden);

IEnumerable<int> query =
    from uf in unmatched_first
    from x in unmatched_first[uf.Key].Zip(unmatched_hidden[uf.Key])
    select uf.Key;

int wp = query.Count();

Console.WriteLine($"Same Place: {sp}, Wrong Place: {wp}");
```

That seems to work now.

---

I really like InBetween's answer. I did a bit of refactoring to make it use standard operators.

```
private static (int SamePlace, int WrongPlace) CompareRows<T>
    (IEnumerable<T> guess, IEnumerable<T> master) where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    var guessWithIndex = guess.Select((g, i) => (value: g, i)).ToArray();
    var masterWithIndex = master.Select((m, i) => (value: m, i)).ToArray();
    var samePlaces = masterWithIndex.Intersect(guessWithIndex);
    var guessNotSamePlaces = guessWithIndex.Except(samePlaces).Select(x => x.value);
    var masterNotSamePlaces = masterWithIndex.Except(samePlaces).Select(x => x.value);
    var wrongPlaces = guessNotSamePlaces.Intersect(masterNotSamePlaces);
    return (samePlaces.Count(), wrongPlaces.Count());
}
```

Comment: There seems a case missing e.g. `var hidden = new[]{1, 2, 2, 3}; var first = new[]{3, 3, 2, 2};` prints `Same Place: 1, Wrong Place: 3` because it count the `3` twice

Comment: @derHugo - Good spotting. I've posted a version that seems to work now.

Comment: the bottom one looks like a copy from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75209118/7111561) now?

Comment: @derHugo - It's a refactoring. I removed the need for an `IEqualityComparer<(T, K)>`,  removed some redundant code, and fixed a potential bug due to hot enumerables.

Answer (score 0):

Linq solution just for the fun of it... instructive (allthough overkill) as it shows use of generics, tuples and how you can tweak built-in linq operations with custom comparers.

```
private static (int Guessed, int Misplaced) CompareRows<T>
    (IEnumerable<T> guesses, IEnumerable<T> master)
    where T: IEquatable<T>
{
    var guessesWithIndex = guesses.Select((g, i) => (g, i));
    var masterWithIndex = master.Select((m, i) => (m, i));

    var guessed = masterWithIndex.Intersect(guessesWithIndex);
    var potentiallyMisplacedGuesses = guessesWithIndex.Except(guessed);
    var masterNotGuessed = masterWithIndex.Except(guessed);
    var misplaced = potentiallyMisplacedGuesses.Intersect(
        masterNotGuessed, new OnlyFirstValueComparer<T, int>());
    return (guessed.Count(), misplaced.Count());
}

class OnlyFirstValueComparer<T, K> : IEqualityComparer<(T, K)> where T: IEquatable<T>
{
    public bool Equals((T, K) x, (T, K) y)
    {
        return x.Item1.Equals(y.Item1);
    }

    public int GetHashCode((T, K) obj)
    {
        return obj.Item1.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the ternaries - just `guessesWithIndex.Except(guessed)` would do.

Comment: Also, one potential bug - you use `IEnumerable<T>` without forcing a `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()` and that could be problematic if the enumerable is "hot". That is, if it produces different values each time it is enumerated. It probably won't happen in this case, but it's easy to generate such an enumerable. Something like this: `IEnumerable<int> GetRandomIntegers() { for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) yield return Random.Shared.Next(9) + 1; }`

Comment: @Enigmativity regarding performance in a case (like here) where thi is not the case it is better though to not explicitly use `ToArray` ... and also regarding performance btw I learned recently that `ToList` would be preferable in general as it doesn't need to crop the resulting array in the memory to a certain size